# find the supremum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, partial-differential-equations, infinity

Hi I'm trying to figure out for which values of $w$ of $u(x,t)$ the absolute value of the supremum of $u(x,t)$ is infinity. 
The function $u(x,t)$ is the following. According to my calculation is going to be all the $w=n$ =integer except $4$ and $6$.

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ \frac{1}{2\pi} [\frac{\sin(wx)}{n^2-w^2}] [ \frac{\sin(xn-6x)}{n-6} - \frac{\sin(xn-4x)}{n-4}-$$
$$ - \frac{\sin(nx-4x)}{n+4} - \frac{\sin(xn+6x)}{n+6} ] \} \sin(nx) $$

Comment: What does $\frac{1}{\partial x}$ mean ? Is it $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

Comment: @Nicolas oh! sorry! that is 1/2pi

Comment: please consider taking the time to re-type your question using LaTeX so that it's easier to read for people willing to help.

Comment: @mm-aops I don't know how to do it. Can you tell me where I should go to do it. I'm so sorry for that :(

Comment: sure, don't worry. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics - this should be a good start - once you write your first couple equations it becomes pretty natural, but should you ever need to find a specific symbol you might try this link http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html . The rule of the thumb is that if you put your equation between dollar symbols and type as you'd normally do in plain text (i.e. e^3 + 17x) the effect should be more or less satisfactory, i.e. $e^3 + 17x$

Comment: @mm-aops thanks a lot :)